# uisplitviewcontroller segue to another uisplitviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, segue

I know the UISplitViewController can only be used as the root controller. but is it possible to go from a split view to another split view?

like load the detail and master views with different data and layout?

Comment: Essentially what im trying to do, is segue both master and detail views at the same time

Comment: who said you that split view is used for only in root view controller ? you can use in any of your subcontroller

Comment: really? i thought splitviewcontroller can't be segued into, so.. u cant go from tableview to split view for instance

Comment: you can go from tableview to splitview

Comment: oh really? ill try that sometime, but what i really want to do right now is go from a split view to a split view........so update both master and detail views at the same time. is there anyways to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a segue per se, but it does change out the view controller for another:

```
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
app.window.rootViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
```

where @"HomeViewController" is the Storyboard ID of the UISplitViewController on your storyboard.